# Using a command object in a Spring 3 @Controller with a GET request

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

How can you use a command object with a GET request in an annotated controller under Spring 3?

I'd like to not having a bunch of @RequestParams in my method's arguments, and I have about 18 inputs that I need - so I wanted to be able to use a command object for this request..

Is there any sample code that I could see? I've used Spring 2.5 - and it's easy there - but how do you do it under Spring 3's annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works exactly the same way as with `POST` request - with `@ModelAttribute` (actually you can even omit `@ModelAttribute` - argument of a handler method is considered a model attribute if other options are not applicable):

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView foo(@ModelAttribute CommandObject cmd) { ... }
```

**See also:**

- [15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)